# POJO to JSON convertion when doing post request to a REST service

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, rest-client

I am building a rest client using JAX-RS API. I have created a POJO representation of the JSON the service expects in the post body.
When I do a post using the below code, I am getting a response code of 500:

```
Response docPostResponse = inTargetInitializer
        .getDocumentCollectionTarget()
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .headers(buildAuthHeaders())
        .post(Entity.entity(doc, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

I used tried using the below approach to make sure my POJO modeling of the JSON was correct and this method works fine and my post request is creating a new resource at the server.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   inTargetInitializer
        .getDocumentCollectionTarget()
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .headers(buildAuthHeaders()).post(Entity.json(mapper.writeValueAsString(doc)));
```

I was looking for help in understanding what is the issue with my first approach.

Update: When I tried to get the entity from response, I get the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Problem with reading the data, class com.imagenow.rest.entities.Document, ContentType: application/json.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.reportMessageHandlerProblem(ResponseImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:310)
    at us.nm.state.hsd.webservices.sbm.ImageNowRestBuilder.getDocFromImageNow(ImageNowRestBuilder.java:232)
    at com.aspen.imgnow.rest.InvokeImageNowStoreClient.main(InvokeImageNowStoreClient.java:16)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toBadRequestException(SpecExceptions.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toBadRequestException(ExceptionUtils.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.handleExceptionEnd(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:710)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.handleXMLStreamException(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:742)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider.readFrom(JSONProvider.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1352)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:370)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: stream is closed
    at org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(AbstractXMLInputFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.utils.JSONUtils.createStreamReader(JSONUtils.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider.createReader(JSONProvider.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider.createReader(JSONProvider.java:283)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider.readFrom(JSONProvider.java:235)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: stream is closed
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(HttpURLConnection.java:3378)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3403)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3398)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLInputFactory.readAll(AbstractXMLInputFactory.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(AbstractXMLInputFactory.java:115)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Are you sure that Jackson is the JSON provider being used with the client?

Comment: @Harsha are yo usure that your JSON is actual data that server expects? i think your problem has nothing with Jackson, you need to ensure that your JSON is correct in terms of server

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I explicitly registered Jackson as the provided when creating my baseClient as shown below. However I am facing the same issue with this code as well.

```
Client client =JerseyClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonJsonProvider.class).target(integrationServiceURL);
Response docPostResponse = inTargetInitializer
        .getDocumentCollectionTarget()
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .headers(buildAuthHeaders())
        .post(Entity.entity(doc, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

Comment: @Vault23 I am sure the Entity modeling is correct. As i have stated in my original question, When I create the entity using 
Entity.json(mapper.writeValueAsString(doc)) and invoke the post method the resource is being created at the server.

Comment: That stacktrace shows that you are not even using Jersey as the client. All the packages are CXF packages. I'm not really sure how that is possible if you are using the JerseyClientBuilder to build the Client. It's very odd.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Initially I was not using the JerseyClientBuilder to build the client. Instead i was using the javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder to build it. Once I saw that CXF was being used by the program, I explicitly used the Jersey builder to build the client. However JAXRS is still using the CXF implementation. I am still figuring out how to work around this. Because I am integrating this piece into a larger project that has a long list of Jars already in the CLASSPATH, I am not sure how to force my program to use jersey instead of the apache CXF.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Also I tried to create a stand alone project to test the client and in there i only included Jersey and Jackson Jars in the CLASSPATH. The Serialization and de-Serialization of the objects works perfectly there. So I believe CXF implementation could be causing the issue. I am not sure how to work around it though.